# accessing json property with given values

Tags: c#, .net, json, dynamic, json.net

```
var orderJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(httpResultStr);
                var orderidCount = orderJson.data.orderUuids.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i <= orderidCount; i++)
                {
                    var orderId = orderJson.data.orderUuids[i]; // my fail attempt. Didnt work
                    var map = orderJson.data.ordersMap;   
                    foreach (var d in map)
                    {
                        var receipt = d.fareInfo.totalPrice;
                        Console.WriteLine(receipt);
                    }
                 
                }
```

Im trying to access the ordersMap members with the given values in orderUuids object. Inside the ordersMap Ids contain the fareInfo.totalPrice property that I'm trying to access. How would I go about achieving this?

[![json tree with ordersMap. Trying to access its members with the given values in orderUuids object.][1]][1]

[image]

Comment: Why use dynamic, just derserialise it normally to a strongly typed class?

Comment: it would just use the order ids in ordersMap object as the class so it wouldn't work

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your JSON as **text**, rather than as a screen shot?  On stackoverflow we ask that questions include textual data such as code, error messages, exception details and data (JSON, XML, etc) as text, not as an image.  For why, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).

Comment: it has enough info. I am just simply trying to access the ordersMap properties. Can someone with any knowledge help me out here?

Comment: @userafg can you expand one `ordersMap` children?

Comment: @dbvega yes check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a partial/full map using the JSON file and use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(json)`.

Other solution could be create a partial map using an anonymous type. Here is a code snip.

```
var anonymousTypeObject = new
{
    status = "",
    data = new
    {
        ordersMap = new Dictionary<string, JToken>(),
        orderUuids = new string[0]
    }
};
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, anonymousTypeObject);
foreach (var kvp in obj.data.ordersMap)
{
    var totalPrice = kvp.Value["fareInfo"]?["totalPrice"]?.ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} -> {totalPrice}");
}
```

**EDIT** If you don't want any map use this solution.

```
var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var orderUuids = jObj.SelectToken("data.orderUuids")?.Values<string>();
foreach (var orderUuid in orderUuids)
{
    var totalPrice = jObj.SelectToken($"data.ordersMap.{orderUuid}.fareInfo.totalPrice")?.Value<double>();
    Debug.WriteLine($"{orderUuid} -> {totalPrice}");
}
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot man! I used the second solution of not mapping.